# How to use nested variable abstraction in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write my own batch files to switch npm versions (just for fun).

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('npm -v') do set output=%%i
move "%NPM_PATH%" "%NPM_PATH%-%output%"

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
  IF "%%A"=="--change" (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    SET /A c=1
    ECHO "ID : VERSION"
    ECHO -------------------------

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /on /b /a:d /p "%NPM_DIR%"') DO ( 
      ECHO !c! : %%F
      SET dir_!c!=%%F
      SET /a c=c+1   
    )

    set /p id="enter version ID: (e.g. !dir_1! enter 1):"
    set target_dir= "dir_!id!"
    echo !target_dir!
  )
)
```

I can echo out the right variable I want to abstract.

But how do I actually output the value of `!target_dir!`?

Example:

User selects 1

`echo !target_dir!` will print `dir_1` to the screen.

But when I use next `echo !dir_1!` then `npm-4.0.0` would be printed.

How do I now output `npm-4.0.0` when the user inputs `1`?

Comment: Change this line: `set target_dir= "dir_!id!"` by this one: `call set target_dir= "%%dir_!id!%%"` or this one: `for %%i in (!id!) do set target_dir= "!dir_%%i!"`; the second is the preferable one. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096886/how-to-use-delayed-variable-expansion-to-reference-a-variable-from-a-string/).

Comment: this is the answer to my question.

Comment: though i had to remove the space and quotes `for %%i in (!id!) do set target_dir=!dir_%%i!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Aacini I just needed to change this line: `set target_dir= "dir_!id!"` to this one: : `for %%i in (!id!) do set target_dir=!dir_%%i!`

[See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096886/how-to-use-delayed-variable-expansion-to-reference-a-variable-from-a-string/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the following code with the second suggestion offered by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) used in code and some other improvements:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('npm.bat -v') do set "output=%%I"
move "%NPM_PATH%" "%NPM_PATH%-%output%"

for %%A in (%*) do (
    if "%%A" == "--change" (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        cls
        set "Count=1"
        echo ID : VERSION
        echo -------------------------

        for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /A:D /B /ON "%NPM_DIR%"') do (
            if !Count! LSS 10 (
                echo  !Count! : %%F
            ) else (
                echo !Count! : %%F
            )
            set "dir_!Count!=%%F"
            set /A Count+=1
        )

        echo.
        set "id=1"
        set /P "id=Enter version ID: (e.g. !dir_1! enter 1): "
        for %%I in (!id!) do set "TargetDir=!dir_%%I!"
        echo !TargetDir!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Why `for %%I in (!id!) do set "TargetDir=!dir_%%I!"` assigns the value of the environment variable with name `dir_X` with `X` being the entered number stored in environment variable `id` is explained in detail in [Aacini's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) answer on [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/3074564).

For the applied improvements see:

- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) which is about spaces around equal sign in environment variable assignment and what is the difference between `set variable="value"` and `set "variable=value"`.
- [change directory command cd .. not working in batch file after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) explaining what the command `setlocal` without or with 1 or more parameters does and why in batch code above also `endlocal` is explicitly specified in the `--change` branch inside the outer **FOR** loop processing the arguments passed to the batch file.

It is advisable using environment variables with a self-explaining name in `CamelCase` notation. This has the advantage of knowing what the variable is for and makes it easier to search for all occurrences of a variable. It is a bit difficult to search for a variable with name `c` as a single character often occurs in many strings.

The command `set` with option `/A` means everything next should be interpreted as **arithmetic expression**. This means that the string after the equal sign is split up into a list of strings using spaces/tabs as string separators. Each string which could be interpreted as decimal, octal or hexadecimal number is converted to a 32-bit signed integer. All other strings which are not operators are interpreted as name of a variable whose value should be converted to a 32-bit signed integer. If the variable does not exist or has not a number as value, `0` is used for the variable. Then the arithmetic expression is evaluated and the result is converted back from integer to string. Finally the result string is assigned to the environment variable left to the equal sign. So with `SET /A c=1` at lot of extra work is done in comparison to `SET "c=1"` although the result is the same, a string with value `1` is assigned to variable with name `c`. Therefore it is recommended not  using `/A` on assigning a value to an environment variable except there is a very good reason to do so like a primitive check for string being really a number. Note: An assignment like `set /A c=009` results in an error message because of `009` being an invalid octal number and `c` is not defined or keeps its current value in case of being already defined while `set c=009` works.

When a batch user is prompted for a string, the user has the freedom to just hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all. In this case the environment variable keeps its current value or is still not defined if it was not defined already before prompting the user. This explains why `set "id=1"` is present in batch code above before prompting the user. Well, it is not checked if the user has really entered a number and if this number is within `1` ... `!Count!`, but perhaps this is not really necessary although a typing mistake could always occur.

Comment: My only question here is about abstraction.  why would i write an if statement to do two the exact same thing as the else? that's just pointless

Comment: and i don't how specifying it is an int, is "a lot of extra work" there can't be much more than a validator going on behind the scenes for the difference

Comment: The two __echo__ command lines in the two __IF__ branches are not the same. Look at them carefully. There is a difference of 1 space. The TRUE branch for count values smaller than 10 output the number and the directory name with a leading space. The FALSE branch for count values of 10 or greater output the number without a leading space. The result is right aligned numbers below `ID` for `1` to `99`. Well, if the number of directories matching `%NPM_DIR%` is always less than 10, then the IF condition is indeed useless and __echo__ line of TRUE branch is all really needed.

Comment: You can of course always use `/A` on assigning a string value being a number to an environment variable and let `cmd.exe` do the extra work taking just a few microseconds (or less) to convert the number to integer and back to a string. But be aware of `set /A Number=009` results in environment variable `Number` not being defined and `set /A Number=020` results in `16` being assigned to the environment variable instead of 20 with a leading 0.

Comment: there now it's back to even for you